# access_log gets duplicate entries unless the default directive in nginx.conf is commented out

Tags: nginx, logging, configuration

I tried to configure a custom access_log format by adding this at the root of a conf in sites-enabled:

```
log_format main '[$time_local] [$http_x_forwarded_for] [$status] [$body_bytes_sent] [$request] [$http_referer] [$http_user_agent]';
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
```

However this made all logs double: once in the default format, and then again in my custom format.

This was fixed by going to `nginx.conf` and commenting out these lines:

```
#access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
#error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
```

However this seems really backwards and defeats the whole purpose of this hierarchical mess of confs. What's the proper way to tell nginx what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Why wouldn’t you put these lines into server block?

Comment: @AlexeyTen oh that fixed it... I previously put it at the top because I wanted to log everything. Dunno if I should delete this question since it was so simple... or if you want to make it into an answer I'll accept yours.

Comment: A good answer to this question would explain what access_log directives override others in different conf sections, and link to the appropriate docs for that. It's something that's not obvious.